# List index out of range, not sure why?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I get a 'list index out of range' with this code, but when I initialize `new_list` as an empty list I don't. Can someone please explain why? 
This function takes a list of numbers and 'removes' duplicates.

```
def remove_duplicates(numbers):
    new_list = [numbers[0]]
    for x in numbers:
        if x not in new_list:
            new_list.append(x)
    return new_list
```

Comment: What is in `numbers`? What do you expect `numbers[0]` to be?

Comment: `numbers` is an empty list..

Comment: numbers should be a list of integers, @doctorlove

Comment: And what if it's empty? Give an example of the code you call this with that causes the error

Comment: I wrote this for a codeacademy lesson and seems like they test your code with multiple inputs without telling you exactly. Think I get it now though, thank you. @doctorlove

Answer (score 1):

It's really an XY problem. If you want to remove duplicates from a list simply turn it to a set:

```
unique_values = list(set(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't get `numbers[0]` when numbers is/could be empty list.
Better solution is using `numbers[0] if len(numbers) or None`

Comment: in fact you do not need to initialize list to `numbers[0]` ever, it is enough to initialize it to `[]`.

Comment: yeah, I was just curious why it would make a difference @lejlot. Think I understand now, thank you